# post a mySQL value return using nodeJS express and EJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, ejs

i have a mysql table looking like this

```
  id  photo_name  mob_no Status      url
   4   one          3434  OK          http://foofo
   5   two          434   Rejected    http://barbar
   6   three         434   Pending     http://bazbaz
```

i'm printing it's values with ejs file but i would like to present 3 buttons which will allow to change the status to: Approve,Reject or pending 
lets say it'll return the query:

```
        UPDATE `scans` SET `status` = 'OK' WHERE `id` = 6
```

unfortunately i couldn't find a way to use the post method and return these values only by clinking a button.
iv'e tried to use form with a post method but it didn't worked, i also don't 
 want to fill in a form with text, just press a button that basicly returns a string.

i'm printing the table like this:

```
      app.get('/home/xray', user.xray)
  exports.xray = function(req, res){
  db.query('SELECT * FROM scans', function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        } else {

            res.render('xray.ejs', {result});
        }
    });
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send two params to the same route by query string. Follow this steps:

**NodeJS Route:**

```
app.get('/home/xray', user.xray)
  exports.xray = function(req, res){
  if(req.query.id && req.query.status) {
    // UPDATE QUERY WHERE ID = req.query.id and STATUS = req.query.status
  }
  db.query('SELECT * FROM scans', function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    } else {
      res.render('xray.ejs', {result});
    }
  });
};
```

**Template EJS:**

```
<a href="?id={{currentPhotoId}}&status=OK">Status Ok</a>
<a href="?id={{currentPhotoId}}&status=Rejected">Status Rejected</a>
<a href="?id={{currentPhotoId}}&status=Pending">Status Pending</a>
```

To be sure and improve security you can check the `status` passed via query string, but this should work.

Comment: it's a nice step forward, if i'm adding <%= scan.url %>  insted of {{currentPhotoId}

and i'm console logging here:
exports.xray = function(req, res){
    if(req.query.id && req.query.status) {
        // UPDATE QUERY WHERE ID = req.query.id and STATUS = req.query.status
        console.log(req.query.id)
        console.log(req.query.status)

    }

i'm getting the id and the status sent, lets say 4
Rejected
now let me try to send it back